# Laravel joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 mysql tables

```
**Clients**  
id | name 

**Services**
id | name | foreign key -> client_id

**Payments**  
id | payment_date | amount | foreign key -> service_id
```

**ClientController.php**

```
$sumPayments = Payment::join('services', 'payments.service_id', '=', 'services.id')
        ->join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'services.client_id')->get();
```

**Clients/index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
      <tr>  
@foreach($service->payments as $payment)
          @if($payment->service_id == $service->id)
            <td>{{$sumPayments->where('service_id', '$services->id')->sum('payment_amount')}}</td>
            @break
          @endif
        @endforeach   
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

There are 'belongsTo' and 'hasMany' in my Models.
I try to display total amount of payments each client has paid. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method:

```
Client::withCount('payments')->get();
```

> f you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a  `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

So, this code will create a new `payments_count` property for each client:

```
@foreach ($clients as $client)
    {{ $client->payments_count }}
@endforeach
```